# Щит капитана Америки или Щит капитана Америка?

Tags: орфография, склонение, ономастика

В одном видео было сказано: "Щит капитана Америка"; я же всегда произносил: "Щит капитана Америки". Что же из этого правильно? Или оба варианта возможны?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Америка — в данном случае имя капитана. Склонять или не склонять иностранные имена? Теоретически в русском языке склоняется всё, что можно склонять, но на практике в каждом конретном случае получается по-разному. В Нацкорпусе русского языка встречаются оба подхода. Примеры.

> Студия Marvel, создатель Человека-паука, Халка, **Капитана Америки**, Железного человека и Людей Икс, планирует заключение договоров с российскими издательскими домами о производстве комиксов. [ЕВГЕНИЯ ДМИТРИЕВА,АЛЕКСАНДР КЛЕНИН. Человек-паук в картинках // РБК Daily, 2008.10.16]
>
> Через интернет он знакомится с командой брутального **Капитана Америка** [Сергей Уваров. Суперзлодеям вновь пришел «Пипец» // Известия, 2013.08.23]

В Википедии имя Америка последовательно склоняется (см. [Капитан Америка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%90%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)).

Как видим, единый подход еще не сложился. Так что выбирайте то, что Вам больше нравится.